# Struggling with mock

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

This is the given code I am using to test my react component. I am testing AddCorporateBeneficiaryDetailsForm and addNewBeneficiaryDetails is the function I am calling when user submits the form. If I pass

`addNewBeneficiaryDetails = () => "HelloWorld"`

Then I am getting `HelloWorld` in the console. Which means `addNewBeneficiaryDetails` is being called.

But when I mock the `addNewBeneficiaryDetails` test is failing with `Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.`I feel like everything looks got but don't know why it is failing. Please do answer.

I am using `@testing-library/react`

```
it("Should validate mobile phone number field when given non australian mobile number", () => {
      const fn = jest.fn();
      global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve({
            ok: true,
            status: 200,
            json: () => {
              return { completions: [{}] };
            }
          });
        });
      });

      const { getByText, getByLabelText, getByPlaceholderText } = render(
        <ThemeProvider theme={SomeTheme}>
          <AddCorporateBeneficiaryDetailsForm addNewBeneficiaryDetails={fn} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      );

      fillData("Title", getByLabelText, "title");
      fillData("First Name", getByLabelText, "Tony");
      fillData("Last Name", getByLabelText, "Stark");
      fillData("Email Address", getByLabelText, "sri@gmail.com");
      fillData("Mobile Phone Number", getByLabelText, "0456111111");
      fillData("Occupation", getByLabelText, "SD");
      fillData("Home Address", getByLabelText, {
        address: "Address"
      });
      fillData("Employment Status", getByLabelText, "EMPLOYED");
      fillData("Gender", getByLabelText, "MALE");
      fillData("Title", getByLabelText, "MR");
      fillData("Date of Birth", getByLabelText, "25");
      fillData("Month", getByPlaceholderText, "4");
      fillData("Year", getByPlaceholderText, "2000");

      const submitButton = getByText("Add Beneficiary");
      fireEvent.click(submitButton);

      expect(fn).toBeCalled();
    });

    const fillData = (label, cb, val) => {
      const element = cb(label);
      fireEvent.change(element, { target: { value: val } });
    };
  });
```

This is my AddCorporateBeneficiaryDetailsForm

```
interface IProps {
  addNewBeneficiaryDetails: (newBeneficiaryDetail: IAddIndividualBeneficiaryPayload) => void;
}

const AddCorporateBeneficiaryDetailsForm = (props: IProps) => {
  const [fullHomeAddress, setFullHomeAddress] = useState<IAddress>({} as any)
  const [fullPostalAddress, setFullPostalAddress] = useState<IAddress>({} as any)

  const handleAddressChange = (homeAddress: IAddress, postalAddress: IAddress) => {
    setFullHomeAddress(homeAddress)
    setFullPostalAddress(postalAddress)
  };

  const initialValues = {
    dobDay: "",
    dobMonth: "",
    dobYear: "",
    email: "",
    employmentStatus: "",
    gender: "",
    lastName: "",
    firstName: "",
    fullPostalAddress: '',
    fullHomeAddress: "",
    title: "",
    mobilePhoneNumber: "",
    occupation: "",
    otherGivenNames: ""
  };

  const submitHandler = (values: any) => {
    console.log("---", values)
    props.addNewBeneficiaryDetails({
      title: values.title,
      firstName: values.firstName,
      otherGivenNames: values.otherGivenNames,
      lastName: values.lastName,
      dob: formattedDate(values.dobYear, values.dobMonth, values.dobDay) || '',
      gender: values.gender,
      email: values.email,
      mobilePhoneNumber: values.mobilePhoneNumber,
      employmentStatus: values.employmentStatus,
      occupation: values.occupation,
      homeAddress: fullHomeAddress,
      postalAddress: fullPostalAddress
    })
    console.log(values)
  }

  return (
    <Formik
      onSubmit={submitHandler}
      initialValues={initialValues}
      validationSchema={addCorporateBeneficiaryDetailsFormSchemaValidation}
      render={
        ({
          errors,
          touched,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          setFieldValue,
        }) => {
          return (
            <Form>
              <PersonalDetailsFragment
                errors={errors}
                touched={touched}
                handleChange={handleChange}
                handleBlur={handleBlur}
              />
              <ResidentialAddressFragment
                errors={errors}
                touched={touched}
                setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
                homeAddress={fullHomeAddress}
                postalAddress={fullPostalAddress}
                handleAddressChange={handleAddressChange}
              />
              <Button type="submit">Add Beneficiary</Button>
            </Form>
          )
        }
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `AddCorporateBeneficiaryDetailsForm`?  Does it even take in that function as a prop?

Comment: Yeah, your test looks good, AFAICT. I suspect your test is failing because the implementation is wrong....

Comment: Yes, the `AddCorporateBeneficiaryDetailsForm` accepting function as prop.